# hibernate could not initialize lazy entity after exception in same session

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have one `Product` entity which has `@OneToMany` relationship with `Distributor` entity. Now, these `Distributor` entities are linked with other `Product` entities as well.

E.g. `Product1` is having `Distributor1`,`Distributor2` and `Distributor3` as children. And `Product2` is having `Distributor1`,`Distributor2` as children.

Now, my requirement is to fetch distributors of each product. Now, due to some data issue, `Distributor3` entity got deleted from Database. Hence, when we were initializing the `Distributor` entities of `Product1`, we got the exception as `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.comapny.Distributor with id xx` which is fine.

However, due to this error, it did not initialize the `Distributor` entities of `Product2` properly. By not initialzing, I mean, hibernate did create pojo for those entities but did not assign values from DB and hence all values were null. As a result, we received null values for all the fields of `Distributor1` and `Distributor2`

My thought process is, hibernate did create empty entities while initializing them for `Product1` but since we got an exception there, it might not have initialized them properly but empty entities remained in hibernate session. And then while initializing them for `Product2`, hibernate found them in the session and hence did not care querying them from DB.

Questions:

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. How to make hibernate discard all the entites it initialized previously if an exception occurred. Or how to solve this issue.

Code snippets:
Product.java

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Product{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @JoinTable
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Set<Distributor> distributors = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Distributor.java

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Distributor{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    public String distributorName;
}
```

MyController.java

```
@RestController
public class MyController extends BaseController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/resources/products"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<MyResponse> getproductDistributors(@RequestParam(required = true) List<Long> productIds){
        // Input received as 2 products. i.e. `Product1` and `Product2`.
        List<Product> allProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        productIds.forEach(id->{
          Product prod = myService.getFullProduct(id);
          if(prod!=null)
            allProducts.add(prod);
        });
        // Here, I checked that distributor of `Product2` were initialized to null values.
        //Populate MyResponse and return
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    //Autowire dependencies

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Product getFullProduct(Long productId) {
        Product product = productRepository.findById(productId);
        try{
        Hibernate.initialize(product.getDistributors());
        } catch(Exception e){
          // Exception if any distributor is missing due to data issue.
             return null;
        }
        return product;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as an exception happens on a JDBC connection, the transaction is considered rollback only, so you can't query the database anymore. You will have to create a new transaction. Overall, it would be better if you join fetch the distributor along when fetching products to avoid this issue. You could achieve that by annotating the `findById` method with `@EntityGraph("distributors")`

Comment: But fetching distributor along with product will nullify the whole purpose of lazy initialisation no?

Comment: Well, what is the point of lazy initialization if you need the data anyway? Lazy initialization only helps if you might not need the data at all.

Comment: Yes but we have lots of other usecases where we actually need it. Here, i have presented a simplified view of my entity. This entity has 10 other lazy initialised entries.

Comment: I don't know about your model, I simply answered your question. If you have another question create that here on StackOverflow, but what is the issue with 10 other "entries"? You can declare multiple methods in your repository with different entity graphs that fit each of your particular use cases.

Comment: No. What i meant was i cannot remove lazy initialisation for distributor as it is required for other usecases. Are you suggesting that lazy initialisation can be removed for this particular usecase without impacting others?

Comment: I don't know your exact code, but in general, yes, that is possible